WordPress Block with Interactivity API e Preact Component
Good evening, everyone. I am developing some custom blocks with the new Interactivity API. Within some of the blocks I need to use some complex components that I decided to develop with Preact, so as to optimize performance and loading, as well as have continuity with the Interactivities that are based on Preact anyway. Everything is working correctly.
In this first phase the components I developed them using h() function of Preact, which I call in the view.js and render through render().
Now I would like to refactor using JSX in the components, however.
However, I would like to compile with preact-jsx only the components I use on the fronted, and continue with the standard configuration for the editor-side blocks.
Does anyone know how to configure webpack correctly to achieve this?
